# PHP form submit not insert and show values in url

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

There is a form with insert to mysql. After click "submit" it doesn't insert and open a link with input values:

```
form_offer_add.php?exampleInputEmail1=asdasda&exampleInputPassword1=&exampleInputPasswordAgain1=&favoriteNumber=--+Choose+category+--&targetwebsiteurl=&targetwebsiteurl=&couponcode=&personalname=&personalemail=&personalphone=&location=0&expire=1&highlight=0
```

Why do this, why show the values? Why don't inserting values?

Comment: r u using $_POST in code? or $_GET? your form method get or post? or not defined?

Comment: oh maaaan, I forgot it! :S:S:S, i am on hard work with short freetime... I need to take some nap. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

What's the php file in the "action" attribute of the form? I'm suspecting you are not "reading" the values sent by the form. The values are being displayed because you're using method="get" on the form.